# mysql count displaying more results than expected

Tags: mysql

Here is my query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM jos_mls AS mls 
    INNER JOIN jos_activeagents AS active ON active.AGENTUID = mls.MSTLISTBRD
    AND mls.MSTACTSTA = 'Active' OR mls.MSTACTSTA = 'Keep Showing';
```

The tables are pretty big, so it would be difficult to show table structure.

When I run the count without `AND mls.MSTACTSTA = 'Active' OR mls.MSTACTSTA = 'Keep Showing'`, I get an expected result (around 500).  But when I want to filter down with those arguments, it kicks back 25000+ results, when it should be under 500.

I figure it's a syntax issue, but looking up similar questions, I could not come up with a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `WHERE` clause

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM jos_mls AS mls 
    INNER JOIN jos_activeagents AS active ON active.AGENTUID = mls.MSTLISTBRD
    WHERE mls.MSTACTSTA = 'Active' OR mls.MSTACTSTA = 'Keep Showing';
```

Comment: It is recommended not to mix two join syntax versions: Either use `select * from a,b where` or `select * from a join b on`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
  FROM jos_mls mls 
  JOIN jos_activeagents active 
    ON active.AGENTUID = mls.MSTLISTBRD
   AND (mls.MSTACTSTA = 'Active' OR mls.MSTACTSTA = 'Keep Showing');
```

or

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
  FROM jos_mls mls 
  JOIN jos_activeagents active 
    ON active.AGENTUID = mls.MSTLISTBRD
   AND mls.MSTACTSTA IN('Active','Keep Showing');
```

Answer (score 0):

`AND` has precedence over `OR` so you should use a parentheses around the second part of the condition to get the desired output:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM jos_mls AS mls 
    INNER JOIN jos_activeagents AS active ON active.AGENTUID = mls.MSTLISTBRD
    AND (mls.MSTACTSTA = 'Active' OR mls.MSTACTSTA = 'Keep Showing');
```

The reason you are getting a lot more rows than expected is the actual query you run is same as this one:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM jos_mls AS mls 
    INNER JOIN jos_activeagents AS active ON (active.AGENTUID = mls.MSTLISTBRD
    AND mls.MSTACTSTA = 'Active') OR mls.MSTACTSTA = 'Keep Showing';
```